# How to adjust the onClick event of react.children when child is a react component not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

When creating a component that uses the children prop I would like to adjust its onclick event. This is easy if the child is a DOM element e.g. a Div but if it is a react component I can only edit the component props not the props of the resulting DOM element.
**Edit:** child component should be abstract and is not accessible for editing.

The following works for a DOM element:

```
export const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const handleOnClick = () => {};
  return (
    React.cloneElement(children, { ...children.props, onClick: handleOnClick })
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div /> // This div has a onclick event injected by wrapper
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

The following does not work

```
export const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const handleOnClick = () => {};
  return (
    React.cloneElement(children, { ...children.props, onClick: handleOnClick })
  )
}

const InnerWrap = () => {
  return (
    <div /> // This div does not get onClick injected
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <InnerWrap />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

I have also tried with Refs but can't work out a way to apply to event to the ref

```
...
const childRef = useRef(null);
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //childRef.current is Null!
  childRef.current.addEventListener('onClick', handleOnClick);
}, [childRef]);

React.cloneElement(children, { ref: childRef })

...
```

Comment: the onClick event can be passed down as a prop to the `InnerWrap` because that's a component. You should get away with just spreading the props into it's child components

Comment: If you don't mind adding one more `<div>` in your `Wrapper` component, you can add the `onClick` event on your `Wrapper` component instead. Or if you wish to add the event listener to some specific elements you could use `ref` on your `Wrapper` component, then find its children with lets say a specific `className` and add the event listener to it.

Comment: @dev_junwen I settled with the first option as I couldn't get the refs to work.  Although it has a potential impact on css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

```
const InnerWrap = ({props}) => {
  return (
    <div {...props} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I do not have access to the inner component so this would not work for me.